# NgMock acting miscellaneously?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ngmock

When adding ngMock in dependency injection 
The login.html page is not loaded

```js
var backendMock = angular.module('backendMock',['ngMock']);
```

[image]

removing it from dependency and its working fine

```js
var backendMock = angular.module('backendMock',[]);
```

[image]

Comment: That's expected. ngMock is used to mock $httpBackend in unit tests. You're not supposed to use it in your application. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: so I can use $httpBackend only for testing ??

Comment: There are three $httpBackend: one in the core ng module, that isn't supposed to be used in client code, one in the ngMock module, for unit tests, and one in ngMockE2E, for "end-to-end" tests where the backend must be mocked (or when you need to develop the frontend and the backend doesn't exist yet). What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think you need to add ngMock to your app?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks thats what i needed actually . I though I can use any one of the module to mock a backend that was really helpfull. my backend is not ready yet and I need to test my front end.

Comment: Then you need mockE2E. But you'll need to configure it to let it "passThrough" for requests to static html templates.